# Action bar buttons vanish when toolbar is collapsed

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have created a scrolling view activity that contains EditText's in the toolbar. However, when it collapses, the back button and menu button disappear.

I want the back button and menu button to stay there when the app bar is collapsed, but nothing I've tried has had any effect.

Here is the XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_tool_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:statusBarScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="32dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="56dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/lNameLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fNameLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/assignment_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="15"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:hint="Title"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/lNameLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fNameLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="17dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/assignment_subject"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Description"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/assignment_date"
                android:layout_below="@+id/assignment_subject"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:hint="Due Date"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/assignment_time"
                android:layout_below="@+id/assignment_date"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:hint="Due Time"
                />

            <TextView
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Set Notification"
                android:id="@+id/notification_title"
                android:layout_below="@+id/assignment_time" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/notification_date"
                android:layout_below="@+id/notification_title"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:hint="Notification Date"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/notification_time"
                android:layout_below="@+id/notification_date"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:hint="Notification Time"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/test"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/notification_time"
                android:text="test"/>

        </RelativeLayout>




</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_save_white_24px"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    />
```

Here is the code in the class:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling_activity_add_assignment);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_1);
        //Toolbar toolbar2 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       // setSupportActionBar(toolbar2);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

        }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

[image: normal layout]

[image]

[image]

the first image is how it looks before its collapsed, the secodn is how it looks when collapsed, the third is how i want it to look.

Comment: First, why do you have 2 `Toolbar`s. Secondly, please share some screenshots maybe even for the desired effect

Comment: I have added pictures to the post, and I just found the code for edit texts within the toolbar in an example online, thats how it had them

Comment: which button are you talking about? are you talking about the fab button (round button with save icon)

Comment: No, the Back arrow and the menu button (three dots)

Comment: I have more or less the same problem and my question on stackoverflow also hasn't been answered. could you find a solution for that problem? I'm desperate.